# UnsupportedClassVersionError on Gradle build with only JDK 11 installed?

Tags: java

Getting this error when trying to run gradle build.

> org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Now there's tonnes of similiar questions on StackOverFlow about this, but every suggestion doesn't work that I've found:

- My Project/Module language level are the same (11)
- The bytecode version of the project is also 11
- There is only OpenJDK11 installation I'm using.
- Path and JAVA_HOME variables point to the above installation.
- There are no other lingering java/oracle enviromental variables.

Running `java -version` results in:

[image]

I don't understand what's happening. I can't see how it's using JRE 8 when I only have JDK 11. I'm at a total loss here.

Comment: In your build script add `println System.properties['java.home']` (or Kotlin equivalent if using Kotlin DSL) somewhere and then execute some task. What does it print out?

Answer (score 6):

It may be that the Gradle JVM is still set incorrectly. If you are using IntelliJ, you can change this by going to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle and change Gradle JVM to 11 (or to the Project JDK).