# JavaFXPlugin Compile Error (Java Version)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to run some sample code from ArcGIS github [here](https://github.com/Esri/java-gradle-starter-project).

When I import and try to run the project in IntelliJ Community 2019 I get an error:

> Cause: org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

ext {
    arcgisVersion = '100.6.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
    }
}

configurations {
    natives
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-java:$arcgisVersion"
    natives "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-java-jnilibs:$arcgisVersion"
    natives "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-java-resources:$arcgisVersion"
}

javafx {
    version = "11.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

task copyNatives(type: Copy) {
    description = "Copies the arcgis native libraries into the .arcgis directory for development."
    group = "build"
    configurations.natives.asFileTree.each {
        from(zipTree(it))
    }
    into "${System.properties.getProperty("user.home")}/.arcgis/$arcgisVersion"
}

run {
    dependsOn copyNatives
    mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.app.App'
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.0'
}
```

**What I have tried so far**

I have downloaded Java 11 SDK and installed it. I changed the Java Version in IntelliJ to 11.

[image]

The error is still present even after changing to Java 11.

**Update**

The run configuration window does not let me select java version:

[image]

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754469/unsupportedclassversionerror-on-gradle-build-with-only-jdk-11-installed) - but no answer.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What JDK is used to run the project? Note that Run/Debug configuration can override the project SDK setting. Make sure it's not the case by checking the run/debug configuration settings. What's printed in the console when you run the app? Provide the first line.

Comment: Check the [JDK version set for Gradle](https://i.imgur.com/zmo4fOv.png). Is it set to 11?

Answer (score 39):

I found the answer thanks to CrazyCoder. I had to set the JDK version in Intellij in

> File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle

.

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same error in Android Studio but the Gradle dialog does not have the option to choose the Gradle JVM. Any ideas?

Comment: For those who use `./gradlew` directly sometimes, you have to point `JAVA_HOME` to that JDK as well.

Comment: Of course! Plugins compiled into newer bytecode won't be able to run on an older JVM.