# Build the project using gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have so far used maven to build the java code.
I was trying to build this project which is using gradle: https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/anomaly-detection

I followed the below steps and it is failing continuously in build.

After cloning the code,

Step 1: As per the steps mentioned in the link, I installed java first and set the Java home and path like below

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Step 2 : I tried to build the project using gradlew like below and end up with the error,

```
anomaly-detection]# ./gradlew
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/host/eclipse_back/opendistro/anomaly-detection/build.gradle' line: 55

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'opendistro-anomaly-detection'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'elasticsearch.esplugin']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'PluginBuildPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type PluginBuildPlugin.
         > org/elasticsearch/gradle/plugin/PluginPropertiesExtension has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```

Why it's failing? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your build environment for gradle to use a more recent java version. You can set the java version with the [gradle property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) `org.gradle.java.home`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=<path to JDK home>
```

Comment: Hi @Mohamad.K I Installed the jdk 14 and then I tried this and end up with the same error and is says Build file '/host/eclipse_back/opendistro/anomaly-detection/build.gradle' line: 55

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use Java 8 and in the [README](https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/anomaly-detection#setup) they want to use Java 14.

> To build from command line set JAVA_HOME to point to a JDK 14 before running ./gradlew

Then it should be possible to build and test the project with the following command:

```sh
./gradlew build
```

**EDIT**:

Can you check your configuration of your IDE. Did the Gradle JVM use the correct Java version? If you are using Intellik you can check it following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754469/unsupportedclassversionerror-on-gradle-build-with-only-jdk-11-installed):

Comment: Hi @flaxel, I Installed the jdk 14 and then I tried this and end up with the same error